# Can I record in HFR mode on the RX100 V using the Remote Camera API?

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

Can I record in HFR mode (240fps) on the RX100 V using the Remote Camera API? I’m wanting to create an app for a slow motion video booth so I don’t have to have someone manning it the whole time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first. Identify how to ask questions and what type of questions should be asked.

Comment: RX100 V still have a bad firmware.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260741/sony-camera-dsc-rx100m5-remote-api

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to use the Camera Remote API with the RX100 V? I am currently only showing support for the RX100 M3, RX100 M4 and RX100 M5.

If you are able to use the API then here is a full list of all available movie quality settings that can be used with the Camera Remote API. Of course these settings will be based on the capability of the Camera being used.

```
value         explanation

"PS"          MP4, 1920x1080 60p/50p
"HQ"          MP4, 1920x1080 30p/25p
"STD"         MP4, 1280x720 30p/25p
"VGA"         MP4, 640x480 30p/25p
"SLOW"        MP4, 1280x720 30p (Imaging frame rate: 60p)
"SSLOW"       MP4, 1280x720 30p/25p (Imaging frame rate: 120p/100p)
"HS120"       MP4, 1280x720 120p
"HS100"       MP4, 1280x720 100p
"HS240"       MP4, 800x480 240p
"HS200"       MP4, 800x480 200p
"50M 60p"     XAVC S, 1920x1080 60p 50Mbps
"50M 50p"     XAVC S, 1920x1080 50p 50Mbps
"50M 30p"     XAVC S, 1920x1080 30p 50Mbps
"50M 25p"     XAVC S, 1920x1080 25p 50Mbps
"50M 24p"     XAVC S, 1920x1080 24p 50Mbps
"100M 120p"   XAVC S, 1920x1080 120p 100Mbps
"100M 100p"   XAVC S, 1920x1080 100p 100Mbps
"60M 120p"    XAVC S, 1920x1080 120p 60Mbps
"60M 100p"    XAVC S, 1920x1080 100p 60Mbps
"100M 240p"   XAVC S, 1280x720 240p 100Mbps
"100M 200p"   XAVC S, 1280x720 200p 100Mbps
"60M 240p"    XAVC S, 1280x720 240p 60Mbps
"60M 200p"    XAVC S, 1280x720 200p 60Mbps
"100M 30p"    XAVC S, 3840x2160 30p 100Mbps
"100M 25p"    XAVC S, 3840x2160 25p 100Mbps
"100M 24p"    XAVC S, 3840x2160 24p 100Mbps
"60M 30p"     XAVC S, 3840x2160 30p 60Mbps
"60M 25p"     XAVC S, 3840x2160 25p 60Mbps
"60M 24p"     XAVC S, 3840x2160 24p 60Mbps
```